# Rxjs: How to combine Observables of same type into single observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to convert multiple observables of type Observable <Event>  into a single observable of type Observable<Event []>. I have tried the following:

```
getEventsForAdmin()  {
return this.userProvider.getCurrentUser().switchMap(user => {
  return from(user.eventAdminList).flatMap((event : string) => {
    return (this.getEvent(event).toArray());
  })});
}
```

This function has the correct return type I need, but when I try to use to use it in my template, it is blank.

If I don't use .ToArray(), then I get an Observable, but I cannot use this with *ngFor in my template.

```
getEventsForAdmin()  {
return this.userProvider.getCurrentUser().switchMap(user => {
  return from(user.eventAdminList).flatMap((event : string) => {
    return (this.getEvent(event));
  })});
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You already have an observable of the list though, but then you flatmap it. Flatmap turns an observable of an array into an observable of the single items in your array. Just only return this line "return from(user.eventAdminList)"

Comment: `forkJoin(user.eventAdminList.map(event => this.getEvent(event)))`